# Extract rows from table, into another table, where value in column = external value

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a formula that would allow me to extract rows from a table where the value in the first column is equal to a reference?
See the table below:

[image]

If the value in the first column is equal to 13:00:00, as it is on the right of the pic, extract the relevant row onto a new table. I have attached the spreadsheet to play with.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/eaz7no3263vl3sd/Table.xlsx/file

Answer (score 0):

Just FILTER the range against the reference value:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759